# How to Get Bootstrap Card Columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning the Bootstrap framework and am attempting to make a two column card system to allow a "feed" of cards to be captured. Depending on the card type it will sit on the left or the right column. I'm using Bootstrap with what I believe to be a 12 column container. Inside the container there is a 6 column div and another 6 column div but for whatever reason they do not separate and all the cards end up being one long list of cards.

Example here:
http://codepen.io/jasonrpan/pen/KaLRdj

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
        <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Left 1</h4>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
        <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Left 2</h4>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
        <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Right 1</h4>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h1 class="card-text good-review-score float-left">8.0</h1>
        <h4 class="card-title">Card on the Right 1</h4>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <p class="card-text text-right">Footer Text - Possible Link Out</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Curious on why this might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/ you have to add a div with the class row around the columns.

Example here: http://codepen.io/Spreadyy/pen/aprrBG.

```
<div class="row">
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much. Thanks for pointing back to documentation as well.

Answer (score 3):

Columns *always* must be within `row`...

> Rows are horizontal groups of columns that ensure your columns are
>   lined up properly. We use the negative margin method on .row to ensure
>   all your content is aligned properly down the left side. Content
>   should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate
>   children of rows.

http://www.codeply.com/go/4GRZdVJ4KM